# Why are $\sin,\cos,\tan$ continuous

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, trigonometry, continuity, elementary-functions

I'm done with two courses in Analysis, but just can't seem to work out how I'll show the base trigonometric functions to be continuous.

Any references or indications for a simple, preferably elementary proof ?

Is it possible to do it relying only on $\epsilon$-$\delta$ arguments?

Comment: Do you understand why the exponential function is continous?

Comment: $you only need to consider $\sin(x)$ for example, because $\cos(x)$ is just $sin(x+\pi/2)$, and $\tan(x)$ is defined as the quotient of the first two, so it is continuous provided $\cos(x)$ is different from zero

Comment: $\tan$ isn't continuous.

Comment: For sin and cos, look at the graph... The def is manufactured exactly in a way to apply to the "intuitively" continuous functions: we can draw their graph without lifting the pen.

Comment: Rudin has this all worked out in Chapter 8, "Some Special Functions", of *Principles of Mathematical Analysis, Third Edition*.

Comment: @K.defaoite: Yes it is, since it is continuous at each point in its domain. (The domain is not *connected*, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: @Hans Lundmark Good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, using the fact that $$\cos(p)-\cos(q)=-2\sin\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{a-b}{2}\right),$$
yields
$$|\cos(x+h)-\cos(x)|=2\left|\sin\left(\frac{2x+h}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{h}{2}\right)\right|\leq |h|.$$

If $\varepsilon >0$, take $\delta =\varepsilon $ and thus $$|h|\leq \delta \implies |\cos(x+h)-\cos(x)|\leq \varepsilon .$$

This prove the continuity of the cosine function. Do the same with the sine function gives the wished result.